# Which Ubuntu distro is fully compatible with Hp pavilion 15n-205tx Laptop?

Tags: wireless, drivers, hp, compatibility, ralink

I had recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 and 13.10, however I went back to Windows OS as both the version didn't Supported laptop's wifi (Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe)

```
Hardblock:yes
```

I have tried installing driver by refering http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104690 but it end with an error while running

```
 make install
```

as tried to

```
 sudo modprobe rt3290sta
```

getting "rt3290sta" dir doesn't exist.

I have also tried blacklisting rt2800pci and rt2x00pci in  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file

the last option was changing the version of kernel but it also didn't worked.

If anyone have the Solution for this please reply or let me know which distro is compatible with Hp pavilion 15n-205tx.

Comment: What was not working about the default rt2800pci?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Fn keys on your laptop? Many laptops can toggle the wifi on/off from the keyboard to save power.

[Enable the Fn keys](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108)
Here is the guide for your [Laptop](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03837811)

Answer (score -1):

I googled your problem and hope you check this link it has a solved problem with the same issue you have i believe.

http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=35938

hope this work for you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Askubuntu. Thanks for your answer. We prefer it if you include the information you link to in your answer, instead of just linking to it. This is to ensure that when the external site goes down, we still have the information here. I downvoted your answer because of this. If you improve your answer, add a comment with @galgalesh in it, and I will remove the downvote.